# Automatically install pysvn in python3 venv

Tags: python, python-venv, pysvn

I can use `python3 -m venv virtualenv` to make a sandbox, but have no idea about how to install `pysvn` in it, because it can't be installed by pip.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't pip find pysvn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609730/why-cant-pip-find-pysvn)

Comment: No, because actually I know "Why can't pip find pysvn" and "how to install pysvn manually". What I don't know is "How to automatically install in venv". Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you can follow those instructions after you've activated your venv. The only "automatic" way to get packages that I know of is to use a requirements file to load things in, but looks like how pysvn is set up, you'll have to do the manual installation at some point, whether you set up a batch file/shell script to automate it. (That means you have to make sure your environment has all the necessary build infrastructure, though.)